# Mudar estrutura do array em php

Tags: php

```css
.tabela-grid{
 margin: 0;
 display: table;
 width: 100%; 
}
.tabela-grid *{
 vertical-align: top;
 text-align: center;
}
.tabela-grid img{
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block; 
}
.tabela-columm{
 display: table-cell;
}
.tabela-columm:nth-child(even) .tabela-cell{
 display: table;
}

.tabela-cell{
 display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabela-grid">
  <div class="tabela-columm" style="background-color: red">
    item1 </div>
  <div class="tabela-columm" style="background-color: green">
    <div class="tabela-cell">item2</div>
    <div class="tabela-cell">item3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabela-columm" style="background-color: red">
    item4 </div>
  <div class="tabela-columm" style="background-color: green">
    <div class="tabela-cell">item5</div>
    <div class="tabela-cell">item6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tenho um `array` que vem com o seguinte conteudo:

```
    array (size=6)
      0 => 
        array (size=6)
          'href' => string 'href' 
          'likes' => int 2
          'img' => string 'href'
          'text' => string 'comentario' 
          'width' => int 370
          'height' => int 370
      1 => 
        array (size=6)
          'href' => string 'href' 
          'likes' => int 12
          'img' => string 'href' 
          'text' => string 'comentario' 
          'width' => int 175
          'height' => int 175
      2 => 
        array (size=6)
          'href' => string 'href'
          'likes' => int 7
          'img' => string 'href'
          'text' => string 'comentario'
          'width' => int 175
          'height' => int 175
      3 => 
        array (size=6)
          'href' => string 'href'
          'likes' => int 1
          'img' => string 'href'
          'text' => string 'comentario'
          'width' => int 370
          'height' => int 370
      4 => 
        array (size=6)
          'href' => string 'href'
          'likes' => int 6
          'img' => string 'href'
          'text' => string 'comentario'
          'width' => int 175
          'height' => int 175
      5 => 
        array (size=6)
          'href' => string 'href'
          'likes' => int 5
          'img' => string 'href'
          'text' => string 'comentario'
          'width' => int 175
          'height' => int 175
```

preciso converte-lo para esse formato:

```
    array (size=2)
        0 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => 
                array (size=6)
                      'href' => string 'href' 
                      'likes' => int 2
                      'img' => string 'href'
                      'text' => string 'comentario' 
                      'width' => int 370
                      'height' => int 370
              1 => 
                array (size=2)
                  0 => 
                  array (size=6)
                      'href' => string 'href' 
                      'likes' => int 12
                      'img' => string 'href' 
                      'text' => string 'comentario' 
                      'width' => int 175
                      'height' => int 175
                  1 => 
                    array (size=6)
                      'href' => string 'href'
                      'likes' => int 7
                      'img' => string 'href'
                      'text' => string 'comentario'
                      'width' => int 175
                      'height' => int 175
        1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=6)
                  'href' => string 'href' 
                  'likes' => int 2
                  'img' => string 'href'
                  'text' => string 'comentario' 
                  'width' => int 370
                  'height' => int 370
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => 
              array (size=6)
                  'href' => string 'href' 
                  'likes' => int 12
                  'img' => string 'href' 
                  'text' => string 'comentario' 
                  'width' => int 175
                  'height' => int 175
              1 => 
                array (size=6)
                  'href' => string 'href'
                  'likes' => int 7
                  'img' => string 'href'
                  'text' => string 'comentario'
                  'width' => int 175
                  'height' => int 175
```

é possível fazer dessa forma? estou fazendo alguns teste então simplifiquei os dados para facilitar, mas ainda não consegui:

```
    $entrada = array( 'item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6');

    $saida= array(
        0 => array( 0 => 'item1', 1 => array(0 => 'item2', 1 => 'item3')  ),    
        1 => array( 0 => 'item4', 1 => array(0 => 'item5', 1 => 'item6')  ),
    );
```

esse array ira popular essa tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você poderia explicar o *porque* deseja fazer isto.. e se tem alguma lógica no processo, ou seria simplesmente por tornar mais complexo a estrutura?

Comment: por causa de uma tabela no frontend da aplicação, vou colocar a imagem:

Comment: Também não entendi muito bem o porque disso, pra mim isso só a torna mais complexa de se trabalhar

Comment: a tabela que ira exibir esse array ja estava assim

Comment: Você pode postar o código do array de entrada? Vou fazer um exemplo aqui e não quero montar tudo de novo kkkkkk

Comment: Certo.. Me parece que deveria haver alguma lógica na estruturação dessa matriz, que você não está deixando muito claro. Sem entender a lógica dessa estrutura não há muito que fazer senão só dividir o array em partes arbitrárias dento de outro.

Comment: a entrada é essa da variavel `$entrada = array(“item1”,”item2”,”item3”, “item4”,”item5”,”item6”);` o que está complicando é que a entrada é um array simples, se for possivel popular a tabela com esse mesmo array ajuda bastante!

Comment: @IsraelMerljak adicionei a estrutura da tabela!

Comment: @HebertdeLima "item1", "item2" e "item3" tem alguma relação?? Se não tiver, a resposta do Woton vale pra você.. mas ainda acho que se esse array aumentar, vai se tornar inviável essa abordagem.

Comment: @IsraelMerljak vou testar a resposta do woton mas acho que vai dar certo, faz todo sentido a lógica dele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio ter um jeito melhor de organizar isso, pois acho que do jeito que você quer ficará muito complexo de se trabalhar com o array, mas como a preferência é sua, aqui está o código:

```
$entrada = array( 'item1' => array('href' => 'href', 
                                  'likes' => 2,
                                  'img' => 'href',
                                  'text' => 'comentario',
                                  'width' => 370,
                                  'height' => 370), 
                'item2' =>  array('href' => 'href', 
                                  'likes' => 2,
                                  'img' => 'href',
                                  'text' => 'comentario',
                                  'width' => 370,
                                  'height' => 370), 
                'item3' => array('href' => 'href', 
                                  'likes' => 2,
                                  'img' => 'href',
                                  'text' => 'comentario',
                                  'width' => 370,
                                  'height' => 370), 
                'item4' => array('href' => 'href', 
                                  'likes' => 2,
                                  'img' => 'href',
                                  'text' => 'comentario',
                                  'width' => 370,
                                  'height' => 370), 
                'item5' => array('href' => 'href', 
                                  'likes' => 2,
                                  'img' => 'href',
                                  'text' => 'comentario',
                                  'width' => 370,
                                  'height' => 370), 
                'item6' => array('href' => 'href', 
                                  'likes' => 2,
                                  'img' => 'href',
                                  'text' => 'comentario',
                                  'width' => 370,
                                  'height' => 370));

$saida = array();

array_push($saida, array( 0 => $entrada['item1'], 1 => array(0 => $entrada['item2'], 1 => $entrada['item3'])));
array_push($saida, array( 0 => $entrada['item4'], 1 => array(0 => $entrada['item5'], 1 => $entrada['item6'])));
var_dump($saida);
```

A saída será:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=6)
          'href' => string 'href' (length=4)
          'likes' => int 2
          'img' => string 'href' (length=4)
          'text' => string 'comentario' (length=10)
          'width' => int 370
          'height' => int 370
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=6)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=6)
              ...
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=6)
          'href' => string 'href' (length=4)
          'likes' => int 2
          'img' => string 'href' (length=4)
          'text' => string 'comentario' (length=10)
          'width' => int 370
          'height' => int 370
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=6)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=6)
              ...
```

As reticências é pelo tamanho grande, para acessar é só fazer:

```
$saida[0][0] , $saida[0][1] , $saida[0][1][0] ou $saida[0][1][1]
$saida[1][0] , $saida[1][1] , $saida[1][1][0] ou  $saida[1][1][1]
```

Comment: Vlw! deu certo, só uma dúvida, nesse caso vc usou mapear direto o `array ` pq sabia o tamanho dele, mas e em um ambiente que vc não sabe o tamanho do `array`? por exemplo se ouver mais um 1 item nesse array, eu precisaria colocar mais: `array_push($saida, array( 0 => $entrada['item7']));` etc

Comment: achei a solução:
for ($i=0; $i < count($entrada); $i++) { 
    array_push($saida, array( 0 => $entrada[$i], 1 => array(0 => $entrada[$i], 1 => $entrada[$i])));
   }

Comment: @HebertdeLima sim essa é uma solução, porem, é bom fazer um tratamento pois, ela espera 3 index para cada push, se vc tiver até o item7 por exemplo, na hora do 3 push ele deve dar erro por não existir o item8 e o item9

Comment: @HebertdeLima vc pode usar um   if(isset($entrada[posição]))

Comment: vlw agora ficou completa a solução, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Apesar de a resposta do Woton já ter sido satisfatória para você, me dei o trabalho de fazer algo um pouco mais 'automatizado' diria.

Já que você comentou sobre a possibilidade de não saber o tamanho do array, fiz de forma que essa estrutura é criada de maneira programática. Dividindo o array em subArrays sendo que num exemplo `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` daria a resposta `[[1,[2,3]],[4,[5,6]],[7,[8]]]`.

```
$entrada = [
  '0' => [
    'href' => 'href',
    'likes' => 2,
    'img' => 'item1',
    'text' => 'comentario',
    'width' => 370,
    'height' => 370
  ], 
  '1' =>  [
    'href' => 'href', 
      'likes' => 2,
      'img' => 'item2',
      'text' => 'comentario',
      'width' => 370,
      'height' => 370
    ], 
  '2' => [
    'href' => 'href', 
      'likes' => 2,
      'img' => 'item3',
      'text' => 'comentario',
      'width' => 370,
      'height' => 370
    ], 
  '3' => [
    'href' => 'href', 
      'likes' => 2,
      'img' => 'item4',
      'text' => 'comentario',
      'width' => 370,
      'height' => 370
    ], 
  '4' => [
    'href' => 'href', 
      'likes' => 2,
      'img' => 'item5',
      'text' => 'comentario',
      'width' => 370,
      'height' => 370
    ],
  '5' => [
    'href' => 'href', 
      'likes' => 2,
      'img' => 'item6',
      'text' => 'comentario',
      'width' => 370,
      'height' => 370
    ],
  '6' => [
    'href' => 'href', 
      'likes' => 2,
      'img' => 'item7',
      'text' => 'comentario',
      'width' => 370,
      'height' => 370
    ]
];
```

```
$i = $j = 0;
$saida = [];

for($i = 0; $i < count($entrada); $i+=3) {
  $outer = [];
  $outer[] = $entrada[$i];

  $inner = [];
  for($j = $i + 1; $j < count($entrada) && $j < (($i + 1) + 2); $j++) {
    $inner[] = $entrada[$j];
  }
  $outer[] = $inner;
  $saida[] = $outer;
}

print_r($saida);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [href] => href
                    [likes] => 2
                    [img] => item1
                    [text] => comentario
                    [width] => 370
                    [height] => 370
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [href] => href
                            [likes] => 2
                            [img] => item2
                            [text] => comentario
                            [width] => 370
                            [height] => 370
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [href] => href
                            [likes] => 2
                            [img] => item3
                            [text] => comentario
                            [width] => 370
                            [height] => 370
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [href] => href
                    [likes] => 2
                    [img] => item4
                    [text] => comentario
                    [width] => 370
                    [height] => 370
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [href] => href
                            [likes] => 2
                            [img] => item5
                            [text] => comentario
                            [width] => 370
                            [height] => 370
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [href] => href
                            [likes] => 2
                            [img] => item6
                            [text] => comentario
                            [width] => 370
                            [height] => 370
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [href] => href
                    [likes] => 2
                    [img] => item7
                    [text] => comentario
                    [width] => 370
                    [height] => 370
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: cara pior que acabei de resolver isso: 
`for ($i=0; $i < count($entrada[$i]); $i++) { array_push($saida, array( 0 => $entrada[$i], 1 => array(0 => isset($entrada[$i++])?$entrada[$i++]: null , 1 => isset($entrada[$i])?$entrada[$i]:null)));}` mas obrigado pela resposta =D